# Google calendar at Thunderbird, without mails - possible?

Tags: thunderbird, gmail, google-calendar

I would like to have access to my Google Calendar under Thunderbird, but I don't want Thunderbird to manage my mails from Google. So, I want only Calendar functionality, without the mail itself. Is that possible?

I have Thunderbird with [Provider for Google Calendar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/provider-for-google-calendar/) installed, I wanted to add an account only for the calendar, but I am afraid that when I create the account for Gmail it will suck and catalogue my mails from Gmail, what I don't want.

Answer (score 2):

Use lightning the calendar extension for thunderbird.

1. Install lightning: 
   http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/lightning/download.html
2. Enable google calendar with sunbird/lightning:
   http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99358#sunbird

Answer (score 1):

You can use thunderbird plugin "Zindus". I use it to sync my google calender with Thunderbird's Lightning calender and it has always worked flawlessly.

Comment: Zindus is for contacts as far I can see, not the calendar...

Comment: Try this one: "Provider for Google Calendar 0.9" extention. It'll work.